# Why can't I import and use machine.SoftI2C in Micropython v.1.13 on ESP32?

Tags: i2c, esp32, micropython

This relates to an ESP32 development module (from Amazon, similar to the DoIt module).  I have Micropython v1.13 (Sep 2020) installed.  According to the Micropython documentation

http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html?highlight=i2c#machine.I2C

there is a class 'machine.SoftI2C(scl, sda, *, freq=400000, timeout=255)'.  By my reckoning, I should be able to do:

'from machine import SoftI2C'

But it gives the error:

ImportError: 'can't import name SoftI2C'

SoftI2C is not listed when using 'help(machine)' (after 'import machine'), whereas I2C is.  SoftI2C does not seem to exist.

This also applied to MicroPython v1.12

Any thoughts, anyone??

Answer (score 3):

You're running version 1.13, but it looks like the `SoftI2C` name was introduced in commit [c35deb2](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/commit/c35deb2625efc877b3a0d03d5654e27232b2d101), which post-dates the 1.13 release.

It may be that the "latest" documentation tracks the head of the repository rather than the most current stable release. You can find the 1.13 docs [here](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.13/library/machine.I2C.html), and you'll note there is no notice of `SoftI2C`.

Try running a more recent build (I'm running [one I downloaded today](https://micropython.org/download/esp8266/)), which seems to be working fine).

Comment: Thanks. I did find the following link dated 2016 which made me believe that SoftI2C had been around for years.  https://www.noradsanta.org/.  Your link to your version of Micropython gave a Not Found result.  Could you post the version or update the link please.

Comment: Those links change frequently. It's just a recent build from https://micropython.org/download/esp8266/.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link, to Santa cruising round the world! You can guess why.  Here is the link I meant to post:  https://os.mbed.com/users/Sissors/code/SoftI2C/docs/tip/SoftI2C_8h_source.html.   I will try a newer version after Christmas.  Thanks for help.